# div containing 2 floating divs

Tags: css

need your help. I created a div that contains 2 floating DIVs. The first Div would be the leftnav. The second Div contains 2 floating DIVs too. The problem #container div height set to auto but not seem to work.

here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seaamx/Y47sx/30/)

I tried the clear:both at the end of the second div, but it didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="first">first</div>

    <div id="second">
        <div id="scol1">
            <div id="scol1a">scol1a</div>
            <div id="scol1b">scol1b</div>
            <div id="scol1c">scol1c</div>
        </div>
        <div id="scol2">
            <div id="scol2a">scol2a</div>
            <div id="scol2b">scol2b</div>
            <div id="scol2c">scol2c</div>
        </div>
    </div><!--SECOND DIV-->

    <br style="clear: both;" />

</div> <!--CONTAINER DIV-->
<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

change `scol1` height to `auto` as well. http://jsfiddle.net/Y47sx/31/

Comment: that one is quick, thank you,  it worked but it still floating div falls out side once height gets larger than the height of container div. I'm trying to make the container div to stretch once floating divs inside get larger in size.

Comment: @user2074014 can you put a fiddle example for that

Comment: I made changes but footer was affected and don't have clue how to fix it. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seaamx/Y47sx/40/)

Comment: I fixed it, thanks though, hope other people get something from this especially using this layout.. [fixed version](http://jsfiddle.net/seaamx/Y47sx/45/)

Answer (score 0):

You have given 100px height to scol1a, scol1b, scol1c. This causes container having problem. To solve this you should define your `#container` `height: 306px;` (100+100+100+6)= 306px. 6px for border.
See this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y47sx/35/)**

**Note: I have removed `<br style="clear: both;" />`**

Comment: I made changes but footer was affected and don't have clue how to fix it. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seaamx/Y47sx/40/)

Comment: As I described before your container is causing problem identifying the height, so you must defined the height of your container coz you have define alter height within container. See your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y47sx/46/)

Answer (score -1):

In stand of `<br style="clear: both;" />` use `<div style="clear:both; float:none;"></div>` and remove height of `<div id="scol1"></div> <div id="scol2"></div>`